# Not getting data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My script isn't getting data from JSON:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#useruname').change(function() {
        var userName = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajaxuseradd.php',
            data: {
                uname: userName
            },
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                $("#fname").val(data.fname);
                $("#lname").val(data.fname);
                $("#email").val(data.email);
                });
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
    });
});


</script>
<form action="adduser.psp" method="get">
<fieldset>
    <label for="uname">Username:</label>
    <select name="uname" id="useruname">
<%
Random Python Code
%>

<%= options %>

</select>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</fieldset>
```

Here's the error I get:

```
updateAdduser is not defined
onchange()onchange (line 2)
event = change
[Break On This Error] updateAdduser();
```

Comment: Have you looked at any response you might be getting using something like Fiddler or brewer developer tools?

Comment: you should do a console.log(data) in your success function to see if you are getting anything back first

Comment: What does console.log(data) output?

Comment: You probably need to parse the JSON back into object form, since it typically comes to the client in the form of a string. You can use the jQuery function parseJSON().

Comment: @SeanThoman I had a feeling that `ajax` takes care of that for you. I don't recall ever having to transform JSON myself. Perhaps adding `dataType: 'json'` would be needed here.

Comment: Your parenthesis look odd after the line `$("#email").val(data.email);
`. Does your browser complain about syntax?

Comment: I agree about parenthesis - something is messed up after $("#email").val(data.email); the other thing is the you're setting $("#fname") while there is no element with that id

Comment: This question is a bit “here mah codez, plz u 2 fix”.

Comment: }); missing } after property list

Comment: It also said no updateAdduser function, and so I added it to the top of the script.

Comment: Now that I've added it, it says undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your IDs do not match. You have "useruname" in the html and "username" in the jquery bind.
2. You should delete the onchange attribute in your html - you are calling a function that does not exist (which is where your undefined error comes from) and it would be redundant if it did - just use the .change() you have in script.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same thing :)

Comment: I have already changed username to useruname everywhere. I also deleted the onchange. For some reason, it still doesn't work, the text fields stay blank.

Comment: Still getting this error: 

missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] });

Answer (score 2):

If this is a code paste...

Could be the wrong id:

On JS: `$('#username').change(....)`

On HTML: `<select name="uname" id="`**`useruname`**`"`

Comment: I did notice that and fixed it earlier. Still does not seem to work.

Comment: Not sure what to do to fix that.

Comment: What happens if you remove this inline event 'onchange=updateAdduser()'

Comment: It can 'overwrite' the jQuery event